# Disable logging for a python module in one context but not another

Tags: python, python-2.7, logging, python-requests

I have some code that uses the `requests` module to communicate with a logging API. However, `requests` itself, through `urllib3`, does logging. Naturally, I need to disable logging so that requests to the logging API don't cause an infinite loop of logs. So, in the module I do the logging calls in, I do `logging.getLogger("requests").setLevel(logging.CRITICAL)` to mute routine request logs.

However, this code is intended to load and run arbitrary user code. Since the python `logging` module apparently uses global state to manage settings for a given logger, I am worried the user's code might turn logging back on and cause problems, for instance if they naively use the requests module in their code without realizing I have disabled logging for it for a reason.

How can I disable logging for the requests module when it is executed from the context of my code, but not affect the state of the logger for the module from the perspective of the user? Some sort of context manager that silences calls to logging for code within the manager would be ideal. Being able to load the requests module with a unique `__name__` so the logger uses a different name could also work, though it's a bit convoluted. I can't find a way to do either of these things, though.

Regrettably, the solution will need to handle multiple threads, so procedurally turning off logging, then running the API call, then turning it back on will not work as global state is mutated.

Comment: What Python version is this?

Comment: Python 2.7. I'll add the tag.

Comment: I possibly see two alternative ways: Add a `Filter` to `request`s logger, or disable propagation on `request`s logger and instead directly add your own handler, filtering records in `emit()`. But both would still require you to determine (in `filter()` or `emit()`) whether the logging call was triggered from your code or someone elses - and given you only get a `record` as an argument, I don't see any other way than inspecting stack frames to determine where the call originated from. Which I wouldn't feel comfortable suggesting for production code, let alone library code.

Comment: Right now a filter of some sort is probably my best option, but I was vainly hoping for a better one. My only other idea was to use a `mock` and neuter the `logging` module with a context manager, but I have no idea what the consequences of mocking in multithreaded code are... and I think my coworkers would set fire to my name in code review anyways =)

Comment: Would the user code use the same `requests` dependency as the outer code?

Comment: Idea: import the `requests` module in your code using a custom import hook - importing it with a different name. This should ensure your `requests` module will have a different `__name__` value and thus creating a different logger. Nothing else would need to change... . Needs experimentation though as I'm not sure this will affect the `__name__` in the `requests` dependency. So it'd require adding the custom import hook before any import is being done.

Comment: I agree that would work, but other engineers on my team have raised justified concerns about readability. Custom import hooks tend to be black magic to engineers new to the project. That doesn't totally rule it out but I'm still looking for a better option. Another engineer also mentioned that `mock` may not be threadsafe -- the `patch` context manager is probably mutating global state. If that's the case, that's another option that I can rule out.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think I've got a solution for you:

The `logging` module is [built to be thread-safe](https://docs.python.org/2/library/logging.html#thread-safety):

> The logging module is intended to be **thread-safe** without any special
>   work needing to be done by its clients. It achieves this though using
>   threading locks; there is one lock to serialize access to the module’s
>   shared data, and **each handler also creates a lock** to serialize access
>   to its underlying I/O.

Fortunately, it exposes the second lock mentioned though a public API: [`Handler.acquire()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/logging.html#logging.Handler.acquire) lets you acquire a lock for a particular log handler (and [`Handler.release()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/logging.html#logging.Handler.release) releases it again). Acquiring that lock will block all other threads that try to log a record that would be handled by this handler until the lock is released.

This allows you to manipulate the handler's state in a thread-safe way. The caveat is this: Because it's intended as a lock around the I/O operations of the handler, the lock will only be acquired in `emit()`. So only once a record makes it through filters and log levels and would be emitted by a particular handler will the lock be acquired. That's why I had to subclass a handler and create the `SilencableHandler`.

So the idea is this:

- Get the topmost logger for the `requests` module and stop propagation for it
- Create your custom `SilencableHandler` and add it to the requests logger
- Use the `Silenced` context manager to selectively silence the `SilencableHandler`

**`main.py`**

```
from Queue import Queue
from threading import Thread
from usercode import fetch_url
import logging
import requests
import time


logging.basicConfig(level=logging.INFO)
log = logging.getLogger(__name__)


class SilencableHandler(logging.StreamHandler):

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        self.silenced = False
        return super(SilencableHandler, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)

    def emit(self, record):
        if not self.silenced:
            super(SilencableHandler, self).emit(record)


requests_logger = logging.getLogger('requests')
requests_logger.propagate = False
requests_handler = SilencableHandler()
requests_logger.addHandler(requests_handler)


class Silenced(object):

    def __init__(self, handler):
        self.handler = handler

    def __enter__(self):
        log.info("Silencing requests logger...")
        self.handler.acquire()
        self.handler.silenced = True
        return self

    def __exit__(self, exc_type, exc_value, traceback):
        self.handler.silenced = False
        self.handler.release()
        log.info("Requests logger unsilenced.")


NUM_THREADS = 2
queue = Queue()

URLS = [
    'http://www.stackoverflow.com',
    'http://www.stackexchange.com',
    'http://www.serverfault.com',
    'http://www.superuser.com',
    'http://travel.stackexchange.com',
]


for i in range(NUM_THREADS):
    worker = Thread(target=fetch_url, args=(i, queue,))
    worker.setDaemon(True)
    worker.start()

for url in URLS:
    queue.put(url)


log.info('Starting long API request...')

with Silenced(requests_handler):
    time.sleep(5)
    requests.get('http://www.example.org/api')
    time.sleep(5)
    log.info('Done with long API request.')

queue.join()
```

**`usercode.py`**

```
import logging
import requests
import time


logging.basicConfig(level=logging.INFO)
log = logging.getLogger(__name__)


def fetch_url(i, q):
    while True:
        url = q.get()
        response = requests.get(url)
        logging.info("{}: {}".format(response.status_code, url))
        time.sleep(i + 2)
        q.task_done()
```

**Example output:**

(Notice how the call to `http://www.example.org/api` isn't logged, and all threads that try to log requests are blocked for the first 10 seconds).

```
INFO:__main__:Starting long API request...
INFO:__main__:Silencing requests logger...
INFO:__main__:Requests logger unsilenced.
INFO:__main__:Done with long API request.
Starting new HTTP connection (1): www.stackoverflow.com
Starting new HTTP connection (1): www.stackexchange.com
Starting new HTTP connection (1): stackexchange.com
Starting new HTTP connection (1): stackoverflow.com
INFO:root:200: http://www.stackexchange.com
INFO:root:200: http://www.stackoverflow.com
Starting new HTTP connection (1): www.serverfault.com
Starting new HTTP connection (1): serverfault.com
INFO:root:200: http://www.serverfault.com
Starting new HTTP connection (1): www.superuser.com
Starting new HTTP connection (1): superuser.com
INFO:root:200: http://www.superuser.com
Starting new HTTP connection (1): travel.stackexchange.com
INFO:root:200: http://travel.stackexchange.com
```

Threading code is based on Doug Hellmann's articles on [threading](http://pymotw.com/2/threading/) and [queues](http://pymotw.com/2/Queue/index.html#module-Queue).